# I have just install new Appcelerator Studio for mobile app Development, but some error

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I just install Appcelerator studio and every thing worked fine.

I have configured iOS and Android SDK, and this is also fine.

But when I import existing or new project from any other resource. then this normal project have **display [master]** tag at the end of Project name and **Some file display as Red Background**.

This is working for iOS and But not working for Android. How I can solve this issue? I am very new in this platform.

[Tap here for right Image, I want to like this Pic, This is showing right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elCwk.png)

[Tap here for displaying wrong with[master] and also some project file display in Red backgorund](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXl1t.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior and part of the git integration in Studio. Read more about it here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Git